# How to extend a query that is generating backend-form-field in Symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, forms, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I want to filter the options of a select-box in a SF-1.4 backend-module according to the logged-in user.
Where is the right place to modify/extend the SQL-query, that is creating the SELECT-Box?

Comment: Are you using propel or doctrine? What version?

Comment: I'm running Doctrine, symfony version 1.4.17.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using the Doctrine version bundled with Symfony 1.4. That's Doctrine 1.2 if i remember correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just overwrite the widget/validator for that selectbox in your form filter class.
I can give you more information but i need to know what ORM you are using.

---

Both sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice and sfValidatorDoctrineChoice have an option named `query`. Use that and set your custom query. So you need to do something like this in you filter class:

```
$query = Doctrine::getTable('Table')->createQuery()->where('field = ?', $field_value);

$this->widgetSchema['your_form_field']->setOption('query', $query);

$this->validatorSchema['your_form_field']->setOption('query', $query);
```

`

Comment: I'm using Doctrine. I guess I just need to add a WHERE-clause to the query, that is fetching the Widget-Options. I just can't figure out HOW to do this.